# Shortcut for multiple columns in query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

What's the shortcut for

```
=QUERY($A:$K, "select A where B contains '"&N1&"' or C contains '"&N1&"' or D contains'"&N1&"' or E contains '"&N1&"' or F contains '"&N1&"' or G contains '"&N1&"' or H contains '"&N1&"' or I contains '"&N1&"' or J contains '"&N1&"' or K contains '"&N1&"'",3)
```

?

I'm hoping for something like

```
=QUERY($A:$K, "select A where B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K contains '"&N1&"'",3)
```

[Cross-posted to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43444023/1595451)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a column (L for example) to count whether "N1" features in any of the columns of interest, say with:

```
 =countif(B4:K4,"*"&N$1&"*")
```

copied down to suit and use that in the query:

```
=query(A:L,"select A where L>0",3)
```

Comment: Oh sigh already implemented long version. Lol thanks pnuts ^-^

Answer (score 1):

There are no mention of shortcuts on https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage, the reference documentation of the SQL statement argument of Google Sheets' QUERY function

Comment: It's not obsolete​, it's a partial answer as well as the other answer.